# Is it possible to access to the workbooks published on tableau server from another computer?

Tags: tableau-api

Currently working on a graduation project. I am trying to set a connection (Ad_Hoc connection) of two computer to allow the second computer to access to Tableau Server and vizualise the workbooks already published on the server.

While trying to access I could not, tried to google the issue but there was nothing.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: is the two computers trying to visualize one published source on the tableau server? When the second computer tries to connect what error do you get?

Comment: Assuming you know the server ip address and the port where Tableau Server was installed, and you try to access it from the second machine by using a web browser, you should provide more detail about the problem you are having: You know all the server info but got an error? You do not have Server details because somebody else installed Tableau Server?

Answer (score 1):

To access Tableau Server from a computer other than the one running Tableau Server or from the Tableau Mobile App, use the Tableau Server computer name or IP address in the URL.

1. On the computer running Tableau Server, click Start, right-click Computer, and then select Properties.
2. Note the computer name that is listed under Computer name.
   If Tableau Server is configured to use a port other than the default (port 80), you must include the port number in the URL. To find the port number:
   2.1. On the computer running Tableau Server, click Start > All Programs > Tableau Server  > Configure Tableau Server.
   2.2. The port number is shown in the Gateway section under General.
3. On the computer or device from which you want to access Tableau Server, type the following URL into the browser:
   ​If using default port:  http://.
   If using custom port: http://:.

Source: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/accessing-tableau-server